# Editing HTML in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, html

I am loading an HTML file in my UIWebView and displaying it in my app. Now I want to all the user to edit this html in the UIWebView real time (i.e. when he is viewing it in the UIWebView). To put it in a different way; Does UIWebView allow editing it's HTML content like a UITextField or UITextView does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It doesn't allow HTML editing.
The closest solution I think of is getting the HTML content and put it in a `UITextView` but that wouldn't be very user-friendly.

Comment: But how do I parse the HTML and extract just the text to be displayed in the UITextView and do away with all the tags?

Comment: Assuming you have a UIWebView with content already loaded, `NSString *htmlContent = [aWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.innerHTML;"];`

Comment: This is not giving me just the text. It is giving the entire HTML code. I want to parse the tags and just show what is in the <body> tag.

Comment: Then go with `@"document.body.innerHTML;"` instead

Comment: @Bogus Boy And if you want the text only `@"document.body.innerText;"` (but you lose any formatting information)

Answer (score 0):

How about split the screen into two view. Web view and text view. Edit text in the text view. When user tap a 'done' button apply the changed text to the web view. Or you can use timer to continuously update web view with the current content of text view.